# Can atom's Windows installer be made to install for all users?

Tags: atom-editor

When I run `AtomSetup.exe` on Windows 7 it places everything within the account from which I'm running the installer.  Other user accounts cannot see the installation.  Do separate users have to do individual installs, or can the installer be coerced into making a shared installation?

Answer (score 1):

Download atom-windows.zip from releases page: https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/latest

You can then extract it wherever you want, make it available for all users and simply set it as default text editor.